# Loading a font from Firebase

Tags: html, css, firebase, fonts, firebase-storage

In my web app, I would like to use the Futura Bold font. I purchased the whole family and uploaded the Futura Bold.ttf file to Firebase Storage. I copied it's link with the access token, and added the following in the style tag:

```
@font-face {
            font-family: Futura;
            src: url(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-project-name.appspot.com/o/Futura%20Bold%20font.ttf?alt=media&token=mytokenhere) format("truetype");
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

However it doesn't change the font from the default and in the console I get the following error:
[image]

How could I resolve this issue? Is storing fonts in Firebase Storage a bad way?

Comment: hi, did you manage to get it work. i am using the same font and for some reason its working when i access my website from my laptop but not working when i try to access it from my mobile. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, it's better to host font files with a traditional hosting solution (e.g. what you use to host your website's HTML), because they are designed for use cases like this, and will do stuff like caching to make the font load more efficiently (which is possible but harder on firebase storage).

That said, if you want to host it on firebase, you can:

Firebase storage enables CORS restrictions by default, which means that it prevents other websites (anything that's not a user directly typing the URL into the address bar) from loading files by default.

For your use case, you'd likely want to [configure your firebase storage bucket to accept all requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration) by creating a temporary `cors.json` file with this content:

```json
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

Then, install `gsutil` by following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) and run:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://your-storage-bucket.appspot.com
```

Make sure you replace `your-storage-bucket.appspot.com` with your own storage bucket, which you can find in your firebase config object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's an email HTML, so there's no hosting, that's why I needed Firebase.